# Outlook Archiving

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using Outlook 2007 at work. I don't use autoarchive, but archive manually, separating emails into months. I have some "straggler" emails that didn't get archived within those months - how do I get them archived? Thanks!

Comment: Move those emails just like ever other email you place in the archive?  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive those emails by selecting them (searching if you want to filter them out by date, etc) and manually adding them to an archive folder.

For example, open up Outlook and search for emails in a month date range, select all those that you'd like to archive, and add them to your monthly archive folder.

Comment: cool, just drag/drop into that folder, or use "Move to Folder" command? thank you!

Comment: Yep, either of those should work just fine :)

Comment: Is there a reason this wasn't accepted as the answer? Did you figure out how to do this? :)

Comment: Not sure about acceptance as answer, but yes, figured out how to do this. Appreciate the feedback and assistance.